# Eliminar acentos pero mantener tildes (Ñ, ñ) de una cadena

Tags: java, android

tengo el siguiente código, que me funciona.

```
public static String quitaDiacriticos(String s) {
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");
    return s;
}
```

esta función quita todos las tildes pero incluye la letra Ññ .. porque lo devuelve como una Nn

Le paso por ejemplo 'ÑOñó'

y me devuelve 'Nono'

necesito que me devuelva  'ÑOño'

Comment: No queda claro lo que deseas, si deseas "quitar tildes"?  , luego comentas que "necesito que me devuelva 'ÑOño'", o sea que lo que deseas aún contiene tildes.

Comment: si claro.  esa función me quita las tildes todo correcto pero incluye la letra Ñ porque lo pone como N ..  yo quiero que lo deje como Ñ

Comment: @Gerard_jor ahhh!, creo que hay una confusión, lo que deseas es quitar los acentos como en "á é í ó ú" y dejar las tildes como en "Ñ ñ", lo que tienen las ñ son tildes :)

Comment: bueno... tengo entendido que á é í ó ú tienen tilde XD .. pero el fin es que no cambie las Ñ por una N

Comment: @Gerard_jor me parece que lo correcto es llamarlos acentos y la "ñ" tiene  tilde o virgulilla http://grumetes.eumed.net/tilde.htm, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias .. mañana a primera hora lo pruebo y te comento..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que deseas es eliminar los acentos (á, é, í, ó, ú)  pero mantener las tilde o virgulilla (Ñ, ñ).

Puedes usar un método donde indiques reemplazar únicamente los caracteres unicode para el acento que son `\u0300` y `\u0301`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para esto puedes hacer uso del método **[Normalizer.normalize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Normalizer)** , el cual  transforma el texto Unicode en una forma compuesta o descompuesta equivalente, lo que permite ordenar y buscar texto con mayor facilidad, de esta forma puedes reemplazarlo:

```
public String eliminaAcentos(String s) {
    if(s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    return Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[\u0300-\u0301]", "");
}
```

ahora como ejemplo llamando el método anterior:

```
System.out.println(eliminaAcentos("áéíóú Ñoño"));
```

tendrás como salida:

```
aeiou Ñoño
```

Comment: me funciono.. muchas gracias.

Comment: Excelente @Gerard_jcr , saludos!